# многократно очистить div от динамически создаваемого содержимого созданного jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Добрый день, прошу помощи у сообщества, т.к. сам, что-то ни как не могу найти решения.
В редактор *TinyMCE* в конец поля редактирования вставляю при помощи *jquery* **div** c **img**.

```js
var arrImgs = [];
$('#jsubmitbtn').on('mouseover', function(){
  $('#images img').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('prev_img')){
      arrImgs.push($(this).clone());
    }
  });

  if(bodyTinyMCE.find('.slider').length == 0){
     bodyTinyMCE.append('<div class="slider"></div>');
  }else{
    bodyTinyMCE.find('.slider').empty();
  }
$.each(arrImgs,function(){
    bodyTinyMCE.find('.slider').append($(this));
  });
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <img src="img/Jellyfish.jpg" alt="Jellyfish.jpg" width="100px" class="prev_img">
  <img src="img/Lighthouse.jpg" alt="Lighthouse.jpg" width="100px" class="prev_img">
</div>
```

Но получается, что очистка происходит только первый раз (при условии, что **div** уже был на странице), дальше картинки просто множатся, а требуется, чтоб содержимое див перезаписывалось каждый раз.
Пробовал удалять и создавать **div** - та же проблема.

Как я понимаю **remove()**, **detach()** , **empty()**, **html("")** позволяют работать только с DOM-элементами, а то что вставляется *js`ом* в дом не попадает (на данном этапе) или попадает раз отображается в структуре. В любом случае, ведь им явно можно как-то манипулировать. Вот только как?

Answer (score 0):

Массив нужно создавать внутри, а не снаружи, как у меня

Answer (score 0):

используйте классы для повторяющихся элементов, id - должен быть уникальным идентификатором: `$('#images img').each...`

ага, вы каждый раз добавляете новый элемент в массив **arrImgs**. стираете содержимое **div.slider**, и добавляете содержимое **arrImgs**, который естественно уже больше на один элемент.

[pop и push](https://learn.javascript.ru/array#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-pop-push-shift-unshift/) -- отличный учебник по js

здесь, кстати, можно обойтись и без массива